# Sean Carroll, can I skip to chapter 8 after chapter 4?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, gravity, differential-geometry, education

For anyone who has studied the book 'An Introduction to General Relativity Spacetime and Geometry' by Sean Carroll, can I study chapters 1 to 4 (which do differential geometry & field equations it seems) and then skip straight to chapter 8 which is the cosmology section? Or must I study the chapters in between which are on Schwarzschild solution, black holes and perturbation theory?

Answer (score 2):

That should be fine, chapter 8 does not really depend on anything introduced in chapters 5, 6, and 7.